# Delete query with integer variable not working

Tags: java, sql

My database contains one column having data type as `Integer`. I want to delete record using that column value but i'm getting an error.

Here is my code

```
int id=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter ID to serach"));
//....code

st.executeUpdate("delete from Table where ID='"+id+"'");
```

I'm getting following error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Criteria mismatch means that the data you are trying to put into database cannot be accepted because the database is expecting a different type of data

Comment: Can you add the Table DDL here. Are you using MS access as database?

Comment: I advice you not to construct SQL with java - this is bad practice and can cause SQL injections in some situations. Use parametrized SQL statements instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass a VARCHAR value in your query:

```
delete from Table where ID='"+id+"'"
```

just remove the `'` and try it again.

I bet your `ID` is of type `NUMBER`.

Furthermore I suggest you to use an PreparedStatement to add the Integer value:

```
delete from Table where ID=?
```

Otherwise you could have some security problems.

Comment: plz tell me insert query to insert number

Comment: insert into yourtable(ID)values(?) or insert into yourtable(ID)values("+id+")

Answer (score 0):

Simple change to :

```
st.executeUpdate("delete from Table where ID = "+id);

                  OR




 SQLiteDatabase _db = null;
DataBaseHelper _dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(_context, name, null, 1);


_db = _dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
_db.delete(TABLE, _ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are inserting integer and not character.Thus no need of single quote around value you are inserting ie int value.It should be

```
st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID="+id);
```

It is good practice to have main key words/clauses in Uppercase.And one more, always try to use PreparedStatement rather simple Statement.

**EDIT**
`PreparedStatement` Example to insert into database

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
    + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write insert query to insert number